# Android.Универсальные кнопки

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Мне нужно разукрасить часть кнопки слева направо. Я использую для этого 2 кнопки, одна поверх другой, верхней кнопки задаю нужный цвет и размер. Как изменять размер кнопки, кроме как SetWidth() я не знаю способов. Получается так, что на одном экране всё работает хорошо, а на другом разукрашивается ровно в полтора раза меньше, чем надо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать универсально?

Comment: `selector - shape - gradient - @android:color/transparent` вот с помощью таких ключевых понятий мне кажется можно сделать то, что Вы хотите

Comment: Можно поподробней , пожалуйста. Для новичка.

Comment: для того что бы подробно расписать, прикрепите скрин того что хотите видеть, а то не особо понятно...понятно лишь что одна кнопка поверх другой эт жуткий костыль)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам стоит использовать для задания размеров кнопок DP вместо PX. Таким образом для разных устройств с разнами разрешениями и размерами экранов можно сохранить примерно одинаковый размер пропорций. Рассчёт происходит по формуле

> PX = DP * (dpi / 160)

где PX - физические пиксели устройства, DP - количество девайсонезависимых пикселей устройства, ну и dpi - dpi.